# `__subclasshook__` on inherited abstract classes in Python?

Tags: python, oop, subclassing, abc

I'm wondering how best I can define `__subclasshook__` on a hierarchy of abstract classes in Python. Let's say I have an interface, and an ABC that inherits from that interface. Is something like this okay?

```py
import abc
from typing import IO

class IFileHandler(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
  def import(self) -> bytes:
    raise NotImplementedError

  def export(self) -> IO:
    raise NotImplementedError

  @classmethod
  def __subclasshook__(cls, subclass):
    return all((
      hastattr(subclass, 'import'),
      callable(getattr(subclass, 'import', None)),
      hasattr(subclass, 'export'),
      callable(getattr(subclass, 'export', None))
    )) or NotImplemented


class FileBase(IFileHandler, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
  def __init__(self):
    ... 

  def import(self):
    ...

  def export(self):
    raise NotImplementedError

  def another_method(self):
    ...

  @classmethod
  def __subclasshook__(cls, subclass):
    if super().__subclasshook(subclass) is NotImplemented:
      return NotImplemented
    return all((
      hasattr(subclass, '__init__'),
      callable(getattr(subclass, '__init__', None)),
      hasattr(subclass, 'another_method'),
      callable(getattr(subclass, 'another_method', None)),
    )) or NotImplemented


class ConcreteFileClass(FileBase):
  def export(self):
    ...
```

Is there a more graceful way for calling the superclass' `__subclasshook__` and dealing with its result? Have I barked up completely the wrong tree here? Any insight would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Use either `abc.ABCMeta` or `from abc import ABCMeta`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to import it as I was just typing some basic code from memory. I'll edit the OP to correct it.

Comment: As far as I know, OP is you :) "The post" is the post.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using the [`abstractmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod) decorator instead of reinventing the whole machinery of `abc`:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from typing import IO

class IFileHandler(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def import(self) -> bytes:
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def export(self) -> IO:
        pass

class FileBase(IFileHandler):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def import(self):
        ...

    def export(self):
        ...

    @abstractmethod
    def another_method(self):
        pass
```

You don't need to explicitly supply `metaclass` to `FileBase`, since inheritance already takes care of it. `abstractmethod` will not allow a subclass to be instantiated without a concrete implementation. Rather than raising `NotImplementedError` in your stub methods, use `Ellipsis` (`...`) or `pass`. That way, subclasses will be able to correctly call `super().whatever` without errors.